# PHP Wordpress gallery not finding the XMLl file

Tags: php, wordpress

The code is below - it uses a wordpress shortcode which is `[my_hmg=widget.xml]` but if you try change the xml file like this `[my_hmg=example_gallery.xml]` it just always reverts to the default widget.xml

The problem is in the function `my_hmg_filter_Callback` in particular these 2 lines;

```
@$my_hmg_file = @$output['filename'];
if($my_hmg_file==""){$my_hmg_file = "widget.xml";}
```

For some reason it always thinks the file name is blank so always reverts to widget.xml.

The files can be downloaded from here - http://www.gopiplus.com/work/2010/07/18/horizontal-motion-gallery/

```
function my_hmg_show_filter($content){
    return  preg_replace_callback('/\[my_hmg=(.*?)\]/sim','my_hmg_filter_Callback',$content);
}


function my_hmg_filter_Callback($matches) 
{
    $my_hmg_package = "";
    $var = $matches[1];
    parse_str($var, $output);

    @$my_hmg_file = @$output['filename'];
    if($my_hmg_file==""){$my_hmg_file = "widget.xml";
}
```

Comment: The simplest way to check is `echo $output['filename'];` or even better: `echo var_dump($output);`.  It will tell you if 'filename' is set, or if it's set to an empty string.  Please add the results to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly change the short code to `[my_hmg file='file.xml']`

Then if you have a quick read of [Wordpress's short code API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) you'll see that the first argument in the callback function are the attributes of the short code.

This way you can the reference the attribute 'file' in the array and get the proper url.